# Half-Brick Image Layout with HTML&CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css, image, layout

Any advice on doing advanced image layouts like the half-brick pattern in HTML/CSS/jQuery? I'd like to be able to rotate or scale the image too. The background-image CSS property doesn't seem to support scaling. Maybe [CSS3](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/background.html) is required but I am tried to target IE8+.

Thanks
Greg

[half-brick pattern](http://cl.ly/G0gL)

Comment: why don't you just photoshop it?

Comment: IE8 is going to make you suffer. This may be your only hope: http://css3pie.com/demos/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You an use CSS3 as you said, but to target IE(6-8) you can use pie to acheive desired results everywhere!!

http://css3pie.com/